# Linq query - multiple where, with extension method

Tags: .net, linq, linq-to-xml

My code works for ORs as I've listed it below but I want to use AND instead of OR and it fails.  I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong.  Basically I have a Linq query that searches on multiple fields in an XML file.  The search fields might not all have information.  Each element runs the extension method, and tests the equality.  Any advice would be appreciated.

```
refinedresult = From x In theresult _
                        Where x.<thelastname>.Value.TestPhoneElement(LastName) Or _
                        x.<thefirstname>.Value.TestPhoneElement(FirstName) Or _
                        x.<id>.Value.TestPhoneElement(Id) Or _
                        x.<number>.Value.TestPhoneElement(Telephone) Or _
                        x.<location>.Value.TestPhoneElement(Location) Or _
                        x.<building>.Value.TestPhoneElement(building) Or _
                        x.<department>.Value.TestPhoneElement(Department) _
                        Select x



Public Function TestPhoneElement(ByVal parent As String, ByVal value2compare As String) As Boolean
    'find out if a value is null, if not then compare the passed value to see if it starts with
    Dim ret As Boolean = False

    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(parent) Then
        Return False
    End If
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(value2compare) Then
        Return ret
    Else
        ret = parent.ToLower.StartsWith(value2compare.ToLower.Trim)
    End If

    Return ret
End Function
```

***Update***  I figured out what is exactly causing the problem.  I still am not sure how to fix it.  Basically any empty strings passed cause the operation to fail.  However, if all (lastname, firstname, etc) have criteria it works.  Any ideas?

Comment: Instead of calling `ToLower`, you should pass `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase`.

Answer (score 1):

One of the test methods seems to throw an exception. When using OR the failing test method does not seemed to be called.

Try to find out which one breaks, maybe because the value to test is null or of a not expected type.

Comment: Debugging Linq seems to be a bit difficult.  I put a breakpoint at the query and it just runs the entire thing at once.  Is there an easier way?